# At Questrade, based on the commission schedule, does an investor need to buy a minimum of 495 shares?

Tags: canada, trading, brokerage, commission, questrade

From this link:
http://www.questrade.com/trading/tax_free_savings.aspx
It says :

> commissions are 1¢ per share, $4.95
>   minimum / $9.95 maximum.

That means , the investor needs to buy a minimum of 495 shares? But for the individual investor, this seems like a very large amount?

Comment: -1 .. nitpicking.  Were you *really* that confused by their commission schedule, or were just looking for something to post? ;-)

Comment: How I interpreted : 1 c per share..Min : 495 cents.so min # of shares you need to buy to reach 495 cents = 495 /1 = 495.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means what it says, 1c per share, but not less than $4.95, meaning you'll pay $4.95 even for one share. The $9.95 maximum means that even if you buy 1000 shares, you'll pay just the $9.95, not that 995 shares are the most they'll let you trade.

seems like a question for https://english.stackexchange.com/